# Coupling 24" and 36" 3/8 flex gas tubing for dryer to form 60"

Tags: dryer, gas, natural-gas

Would it be okay to use a male-male flare union adapter to couple two flex gas lines together to make a 60" one for a gas dryer?

I had read stuff in the past about longer lengths of tubing lowering the BTU rating and was  wondering if that would be an issue here.

This is because the dryer gas inlet is relatively far away from the gas source.

Comment: I'd buy a 60" one and use it.   Every time you add a component, you're creating another potential failure point.

Comment: I would get a 60" stainless flex tube an eliminate two connections and the question. I doubt the flow is large enough to be restricted.